# ubuntu mv file disappeared

Tags: file, unix, ubuntu, mv

On [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu), I have the following directory structure:

```
/var/www/html
```

I am in `www` and I decided to move a file from this directory to `html`. I executed the following:

```
mv myfile.iso /html
```

Now I cannot see the file. Apparently I did not use the command properly. Any help to recover the file?

Comment: Your file does not disappeared. Just got renamed to `html` under `/` directory. Try : `ls -lhrt /html`

Comment: @sat you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, your file is either now called `html`, and it stands in the root directory `/` (I'm not even sure this is possible), or it moved to existing directory `/html`

You must do the following to find it back (second case I spoke of):

```
mv /html/myfile.iso /var/www/html
```

or if it doesn't work (first case):

```
mv /html /var/www/html/myfile.iso
```

Comment: The file has been moved to `/` and got renamed to `html`. `mv /html /var/www/html/myfile.iso` is the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When u need to move a file you need to do this like: "mv foo ~/Desktop",
You forgot the ~ sign. What mv does is also rename the file.

> The mv command will move a file to a different location or will rename a file. Examples are as follows: "mv file foo" will rename the file "file" to "foo". "mv foo ~/Desktop" will move the file "foo" to your Desktop directory, but it will not rename it. You must specify a new file name to rename a file.

You should look if u can find a folder called html in the root.